# CMake finds wrong boost version

Tags: boost, makefile, cmake

I run find_package(Boost) and CMake outputs 1.53. But I have installed 1.62 via the package manager. Unfortunately I need > 1.58. See screenshot. I am using Debian 9, Stable, 64 bit. I am trying to build GnuRadio via Pybombs...
[image]

Comment: Please, paste **textual representation** of the logs, not a screenshots. See [ask] for more info.

Comment: Can you not remove the boost-1.53 development components?  You may need to retain the shared libraries to support applications, but one would hope that CMake would not select a Boost version for which the development components were not actually present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. Apparently CMake checked a version.hpp file which was locally installed (/usr/local/include/boost), probably by me a long time ago...

Funny thing though, there was no corresponding library and CMake was also not trying to look into the default directories. 
I had to do the following:

- SET(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/usr/include/boost")
- SET(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu")

I found the bug by using the debugging flag

- SET(Boost_DEBUG ON)

Maybe it is useful for somebody :)

Comment: Stuff installed in `/usr/local` is often assigned higher precedence than other things, on the theory that it constitutes system-specific customizations that *should* have higher precedence.  As for CMake's behavior under these specific circumstances, well, software sometimes has weaknesses and flaws, and your system environment *was* rather abnormal in this area.